# How to iterate over pandas dataframe and create new column

Tags: python, loops, pandas, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a pandas dataframe that has 2 columns. I want to loop through it's rows and based on a string from column 2 I would like to add a string in a newly created 3th column. I tried:

```
for i in df.index:
    if df.ix[i]['Column2']==variable1:
        df['Column3'] = variable2
    elif df.ix[i]['Column2']==variable3:
        df['Column3'] = variable4

print(df)
```

But the resulting dataframe has in column 3 only Variable2.

Any ideas how else I could do this?

Comment: You can use `for i, r in df.iterrows()` to get `i` as the index and `r` as a Series of row values. This makes writing the if, elif conditions easier `if r.Column2==variable1:`

Comment: I have just realised you main issue here is that you are setting the entire column Column3 as equal to either variable2 and variable4 for ALL `i`. You get only variable2 as variable1 is the last element in Column2. In other words just use `df.ix[i, 'Column3'] = variable2` and `df.ix[i, 'Column3'] = variable4`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this (if you want to keep the `for` loop you use) :

```
new_column = []

for i in df.index:
    if df.ix[i]['Column2']==variable1:
        new_column.append(variable2)
    elif df.ix[i]['Column2']==variable3:
        new_column.append(variable4)
    else : #if both conditions not verified
        new_column.append(other_variable)

df['Column3'] = new_column
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), what is faster as loop:

```
df['Column3'] = np.where(df['Column2']==variable1, variable2, 
                np.where(df['Column2']==variable3, variable4))
```

And if need add variable if both conditions are `False`:

```
df['Column3'] = np.where(df['Column2']==variable1, variable2, 
                np.where(df['Column2']==variable3, variable4, variable5))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column2':[1,2,4,3]})
print (df)
   Column2
0        1
1        2
2        4
3        3

variable1 = 1
variable2 = 2
variable3 = 3
variable4 = 4
variable5 = 5

df['Column3'] = np.where(df['Column2']==variable1, variable2, 
                np.where(df['Column2']==variable3, variable4, variable5))

print (df)
   Column2  Column3
0        1        2
1        2        5
2        4        5
3        3        4
```

Another solution, thanks [`Jon Clements`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873995/how-to-iterrate-over-pandas-dataframe-and-create-new-column/39874053#comment67034759_39874053):

```
df['Column4'] = df.Column2.map({variable1: variable2, variable3:variable4}).fillna(variable5)
print (df)
   Column2  Column3  Column4
0        1        2      2.0
1        2        5      5.0
2        4        5      5.0
3        3        4      4.0
```

Comment: Or possibly: `df.Column2.map({1: 'foo', 3: 'bar'}).fillna('')` - then you've got your conditions (non-nested in a one-op dict) and the `fillna` as a default value

Comment: Yes, only converting to `float` is not nice, but it works nice if variables are `float` or `string`. If `int`, only `.astype(int)` is necessary. Thanks you.

Comment: thanks Jezrael it did work very well. If I am not too cheeky and this might be very difficult, but how can I now replace variable5 with either variable 2 or 4 equitably taking into account that not both variable currently have the same number of rows. In your example if Column 4 would be

Comment: 2.0  5.0  5.0 4.0 4.0 4.0. In this case the 2 5's should become 2's

Comment: @Andei Cozma - I am off my PC. So I think you can ask another question. Small advice check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/2901002) and dont forget add desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, there is no need to loop through each and every index, just use pandas built in [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking). First line here, we gather all of the values in `Column2` that are the same as `variable1` and set the same row in `Column3` to be `variable2`

```
df.ix[df.Column2==variable1, 'Column3'] = variable2
df.ix[df.Column2==variable3, 'Column3'] = variable4
```

A simple example would be

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['dog', 'fish', 'fish', 'dog']})
print(df)

    Animal
0   dog
1   fish
2   fish
3   dog

df.ix[df.Animal=='dog', 'Colour'] = 'brown'
df.ix[df.Animal=='fish', 'Colour'] = 'silver'
print(df)

    Animal  Colour
0   dog     brown
1   fish    silver
2   fish    silver
3   dog     brown
```

The above method can be build on very easily using multiple conditions like `&` and `|` to boolean index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal':['dog', 'fish', 'fish', 'dog'], 'Age': [1, 3, 2, 10]})
print(df)

   Age Animal
0    1    dog
1    3   fish
2    2   fish
3   10    dog

df.ix[(df.Animal=='dog') & (df.Age > 8), 'Colour'] = 'grey' # old dogs go grey
df.ix[(df.Animal=='dog') & (df.Age <= 8), 'Colour'] = 'brown'
df.ix[df.Animal=='fish', 'Colour'] = 'silver'
print(df)

   Age Animal  Colour
0    1    dog   brown
1    3   fish  silver
2    2   fish  silver
3   10    dog    grey
```