# Changing the variables of a Pandas column based on the total number of the index

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
Column1   Column2   Column3
type1     custom1   name1
type2     custom2   NONAME
type3     custom3   name2
type4     custom4   name2
............
```

How could I replace the Noname with in this case name1. Currently column 3 contains an uneven number of name1 and name 2 and I want to end up having half of the column with name1 and the other half with name2. If this brings more insight I have my current columns based on [How to iterate over pandas dataframe and create new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39873995/how-to-iterate-over-pandas-dataframe-and-create-new-column)

Comment: Can you add more data? Only is important replace `NONAME` to `name1` ?. There is multiple `NONAME` values?

Comment: Apologies for that. Column 3 currently contains 1306 rows mixed between Noname, Name1 and Name2. I am trying to see how can I replace the Noname with either name1 or name2 so that at the end of the process my column results in having only name1 and 2 split equally.

Comment: Ok, there is always even length of `DataFrame` ?

Comment: no the length changes based on different inputs

Comment: so if lenght of DataFrame is uneven, how you get half of data?

Comment: based on the index.

Comment: Oh sorry Just understood your comment Jezrael. I would split the column on +1. So it I have 5 rows in total I would end up with 3 Name1 and 2 name2